# How can I stop the Title and Button from moving upwards when I hover the button

Tags: html, css

This has the video of the problem https://files.fm/u/pvuv6shbx

I still want the hover animation of it sliding to the right but I dont want the button and title to move upwards when I hover.

Button code

```css
button{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #0da7ce;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0da7ce;
}
```

Button animation code

```css
span{
  background: #0da7ce;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover span{
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover{
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML markup ?

Comment: add a transparent border on hover.
border: 2px solid transparent;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put border the same color of the background

```
button:hover{
        border-color: #0da7ce;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

just simple change the border-color

```
button:hover{
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your CSS :

```
button:hover{
    border: none;
}
```

to

```
button:hover{
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: This fixed the moving problem but the border of the button dissappears when I hover it now

Comment: Same must have happened with border none too.

Comment: If you want to keep the border you can add a border of same color as that of your background.

Comment: Yeah I dont want to remove the border since I would have make the glow effect also dissappear on hovering.

Comment: How about having no change on the border on hover at all.

Comment: Just removing the hover code